# What is the correct way to define this C macro?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ABS(a)  (a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a)
int main(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", ABS(-3) + 1);
  return 0;
}
```

This code snippet, from Herbert Schildt's book, looks like it will produce the output `4` but it actually prints `3`. Why?

How do I fix it?

Comment: Try expanding the macro yourself and see what you get. Remember that macros are not functions.

Comment: The general rule for macro definitions is to parenthesize the whole thing and use parens around each use of a macro parameter - unless there's a specific reason (that you can explain) not to.

Comment: the next problem will be that `abs(--b)` also gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Uhh... Be careful with Schildt's books. They are known to have [countless errors](http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html). They are known to be so faulty that the term [*bullshildt*](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/B/bullschildt.html) was coined to describe his books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand your macro:

```
#define ABS(a)  (a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a)

printf("%d\n", ABS(-3) + 1);

printf("%d\n", (-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3) + 1); // you can get this with **gcc -E source.c

printf("%d\n", (-3) < 0 ? 3 : -2); //read about precedence to understand this step.

printf("%d\n", 3);
```

This is the step by step explanation of why is printing `3`. You need to fix it using the appropriate parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is to use an `inline` function, with a `_Generic` case for each type you want to support. Otherwise you evaluate `a` twice.

In lieu of that you can fix it by parenthesizing the expression in the macro. That is always a good idea to prevent exactly this sort of problem.

```
#define ABS(a) ((a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a))
```

The problem comes about because `X ? Y : Z + 1` means `X ? Y : (Z + 1)` .

Comment: This solution works. Could you please tell me why it's turning into `Z + 1`? The ` + 1` isn't a part of the call to ABS() right?

Comment: @praroh1 And that's where the problem lies, Macros aren't functions and don't get called, they are substituted into the code. Your `printf` call looks something like this after preprocessing: 
`printf("%d\n", (-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3) + 1);` - hence where the `Z + 1` is coming from.

Comment: @jduncanator - Ah! Makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike functions macros are expanded in the place where they are encountered.
Therefore in this code

```
printf("%d\n", ABS(-3) + 1);
```

when ABS(-3) is encountered it is expanded, i.e

```
 printf("%d\n", (-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3) + 1);
```

So the expressoin is true and -(-3) is evaluated (in your case). If the expression was evaluated to false (say) then the result would have been (-3)+1 which is -2.

To fix this, instead of

```
#define ABS(a)  (a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a)
```

write

```
#define ABS(a)  ((a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix Parenthesis 
    #define ABS(a)  (((a) < 0 )? -(a) : (a))